# Analyzing Graham Scan Algorithm of Convex Hull

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, testcase

I have made a code to implement Graham Scan algorithm of convex hull. I have tested the program by generating some test cases. In all cases it gives accurate result. But My question is, is it possible to generate some tricky test cases when the program may fail to give the perfect convex hull as output? What is the procedure of generating such cases?

Comment: Just generate some random test-cases and check your solution. For huge instances, checking if it's containing all points is easy. For checking if it's a minimal hull, you could generate small test-cases and compare with exhaustive search. There is no way of generating hard instances without knowledge of your algorithm. You could also implement a function generating instances where you know the optimal solution (by construction). But it will be more biased.

Comment: Sometimes convex hull code breaks when points are collinear, especially on the hull itself.

Comment: A stress test is by having all sites collinear, either on an horizontal/vertical or on an oblique line. Also duplicated vertices. If you used a polar-coordinates-based implementation, try configurations with sites aligned with the center.

Comment: To be tried: nine points defined by a square split in four. Then try all 2^9 subsets of these points.

Comment: can you please provide a test data containing the vertices? @Yves Daoust

Comment: @user6823702: No.

Answer (score 1):

As Sascha answered in a comment, it is impossible to help you generate tricky test cases or to know if that is possible without knowing how you implemented the algorithm.

The algorithm itself is of course proven to be correct and to solve the problem. So it's only about testing that your implementation does what the algorithm says.

I would suggest trying to prove to yourself your implementation - prove you are getting the right point as the starting point, prove why the calculations you are doing for sorting are giving the right sorting order by angle, prove that the calculations on which the decision to drop a point or to continue is based on are equivalent to (or directly figuring out) the question of right-turn or left turn and prove that each step of the algorithm is executed in your implementation.

All these proofs can be done twice - once theoretically and then using test codes that will target the specific questions with test-cases built for them (for example to check if the right-turn/left-turn calculations are done properly you don't need the rest of the algorithm - just test a lot of 3-points sets with every constellation possible against the known correct result to test whether the calculation you use gives the right answer).